# Confusion matrix: What does it mean to have 0 value in true negative?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am working on churn prediction data set using logistic regression. The model is predicting 95% accuracy but confusion matrix is giving following output:

```
array([[1517,    0],
       [  70,    0]], dtype=int64)
```

How can I make model to predict true negatives too?

Comment: Looks like your data is imbalance. What's the proportion of the output variable in your training data?

Comment: Could you check if you have negative class in your Y_train.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar how can I check?

Comment: Using `df["column_name"].value_counts()`

Comment: this is the propportion in training data: 
0    4810
1     267
Name: Churn, dtype: int64

Comment: You have a very high imbalance, are you sure these are your output variable proprtions?

Comment: @maverick6912 yes for y_train

Comment: Then you only have two primary classes, that is y_train[1] and y_train[3], actually the other classes have so less data that they won't have any impact on classification. I think your model is majorly predicting y_train[1].

Comment: Also, if you have four classes, then the confusion matrix should be a 4*4.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical problem of inbalanced data.

Your logistic classification is only prediction one class (in this case class 0) and is not respecting any other outcome at all.

There are tons of keywords/ideas to solve this solution which would be outside of this scope here. To give you some buzzwords:

- Over/Undersampling
- Outlier detection
- Change classifier optimization problem

There is no basic solution for this kind of problem, you really need to work on that topic!

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to answer by PV8, as mentioned above this is a highly imbalanced dataset. You could look into different metrics such as `ROC`, `PR curve`, balanced accuracy score, `stratified k fold cross validation`, adjust class weights and try `under/over sampling`. It may be a good idea to try other mentioned approaches before going with sampling.

Since, you are using scikit-learn you can use imbalanced-learn package along with it, https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html. It will provide various under/over sampling algorithms, classifiers, metrics for imbalanced datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Logistic regression errors at times due to scaling issues - try out scaling all the variables regressed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).